# Missing Typescript Options in Web Essential for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I am setting up Visual Studio 2012 and TypeScript. Issue I am coming across is,

Web Essentials in **Visual Studio 2012->Tools->Options-> Web Essentials->TypeScript** all options are missing (Screen Shot attached)

[image: Missing options for TypeScript for Web Essential].

Link (http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/working-with-typescript-in-visual-studio/240154792) Figure #6 which mentions all possible options which should be available about same and I was referring "TypeScript Revealed" book which also shows same options (Page #16). What could be potential issue/missing configuration?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

Web Essentials has removed all the TypeScript options that are now implemented by the official TypeScript plugin. You can find these options in the Text Editor settings or Project Properties now.

Comment: Thanks for clarification !! Can you please share more detail on same? Unfortunately I am not able to view them with VS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Split panes have been reintroduced in the latest version of web essentials: http://vswebessentials.com/features/typescript